# Typescript - Dynamic value in type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Let's assume i have a form, and I want to create a function that returns the current step name.

First step is `stepOne`, the second step is `stepTwo`, and the third step is a dynamic step that changes depending on different parameters, let's assume some kind of id. So its base name would be `dynamicStep-` and it can be returned from the function as `dynamicStep-123` or `dynamicStep-555` for example.

I want to define the return type as accurately as possible, is there a way to do so?
something along the lines of

```
type FunctionReturnType = 'stepOne' | 'stepTwo' | 'dynamicStep-'+?
```

I know I can use interpolated strings in type declarations, but in this case I don't have access to the id from outside the function

Comment: *"...and the third step is a dynamic step that changes depending on different parameters, let's assume some kind of id..."* Is that ID's value a *compile-time* constant? Is it derived from the *types* (not values) of the input parameters? If so, you can do this with a mapped type. If not, you can't do this and you'll probably want `"stepOne" | "stepTwo" | "dynamicStep-${number}"`.

Comment: (Er, sorry, that should have been ```"stepOne" | "stepTwo" | `dynamicStep-${number}`​``` [backticks on that last union member, not quotes])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...and the third step is a dynamic step that changes depending on different parameters, let's assume some kind of id...

If that ID's value isn't a compile-time constant or can't be derived from the *types* (not values) of the parameters, then you can't do this at compile-time. You'll probably want to use `` "stepOne" | "stepTwo" | `dynamicStep-${number}`​ `` instead.

But if that ID's value *is* a compile-time constant and it can be derived from the types of the input parameters, you can do this with a mapped type. For example:

```typescript
type FunctionReturnType<ArgType extends string | number> =
    | "stepOne"
    | "stepTwo"
    | (
        ArgType extends string
            ? "dynamicStep-1"
            : "dynamicStep-2"
    );

function example<ArgType extends string | number>(arg: ArgType): FunctionReturnType<ArgType> {
    // ...
}
```

With that:

- The return type of `example("x")` is `"stepOne" | "stepTwo" | "dynamicStep-1"`
- The return type of `example(42)` is `"stepOne" | "stepTwo" | "dynamicStep-2"`
- The return type of `example(u)` where the type of `u` is `string | number` is `"stepOne" | "stepTwo" | "dynamicStep-1" | "dynamicStep-2"`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsECULDgJwQBVwIAeAQXwHMTIoIAPYCBAEwGcoPh9UFqUAD5QEcALYAjCPgB8UALwBYAFBR1wqACIeEMAHkEELao2adLMEQDu6E2o0iAFKbMaqtUg2atO3XvzUrm5uAPzabCAIAIbiqEgAypYAtACM9iEhAFwRUbHxSXrJAEwZGgCUANyqqgBmiCgYCN6xYAA25B500Ews7Fw8fAKaYlIysk7RNDldpOU58MhomDh4hN2UNN3yAN7BUPi4BM1ibW1Q0VzRCCAXXIuNK0frpJuekLLVKgC+NSqg9Aoin8Q0EIlG0nw3j6fkGgSg4V4cGgOVq0TaHAgX1USEwPAOzwQMHQ+CSoOBTFaHScWkYWiqOLxwAJayJJIAchJIRTGFSIE4ACzFBkqNgQJBtKbQXEIfGMHJw4bgrkyL4y-GHVnE-AAVQQTR5fKcjBFQA)

If you wanted `example(u)` in the above to return a different dynamic step rather than a union of the ones for strings and numbers, you can do that by using `[ArgType] extends [string]` and doing an explicit branch for number:

```typescript
type FunctionReturnType<ArgType extends string | number> =
    | "stepOne"
    | "stepTwo"
    | (
        [ArgType] extends [string]
            ? "dynamicStep-1"
            : [ArgType] extends [number]
            ? "dynamicStep-2"
            : never
    );
```

That makes the return type of `example(u)` just `"stepOne" | "stepTwo"`, it doesn't include a union of the types for strings and numbers, by preventing the mapped type from distributing the union. (Or of course you could use `"dynamicStep-3"` or whatever you like instead of `never`.)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMbAJYHsECULDgJwQBVwIAeAQXwHMTIoIAPYCBAEwGcoPh9UFqUAD5QEcALYAjCPgB8UALwBYAFBR1wqACIeEMAHkEELao2adLMEQDu6E2o0iAFKbMaA2lVqkAug2asnFDuPHwCPq5ubgD82mwgCACG4qhIAMqWALQAjPZRUQBcwV50EH5MLOxc7mJSMhEO+RqxWvFJKelZAEx5TRpFRgBuMpFQAJQA3KqqAGaIKBgI-slgADbkJaT+lUGh-IIitdJyTok0RZuQY0XwyGiYOHiEpZQ0pfIA3qP4uARLYqtVlBElxEggQMCuLcFg9fs9SK9vJBZFMVABfaYqUD0CiKbi8faaI4ybaBLh7ARQWK8ODQIozRKrDgQVGqJCYHhQH5PBAwdD4DJhQQKZbiNYQJxaRhaSZsjnALlw3n8gByEmOeKYK3WTgALF1ZSo2BAkKsztB2QhOYwihSDqJ1TJUZbOdy-nz8ABVBCLTWMbUSxiTIA)

Comment: wow, what a detailed answer, thank you! 

I'm not sure I fully get you so:
It is not a compile-time constant, but assuming I know the type of ID would always be a string, and I want to set the type as either always 'stepOne', 'stepTwo' or a concatenation of 'dynamicStep-' and any string, is there a way to do so, as in some sort of a wildcard for the concatenated string?
excuse me if misunderstand your examples, but it seems to me that it gives explicit values for `ArgType`, but I might be misunderstanding what you mean by "can be derived from the type" and it's then not possible

Comment: @Blueprint - It sounds like my first paragraph applies: ID is not a compile-time constant, so you can't use it to determine the return type of the function. So your return type will need to be broader than you might want, probably something like ```"stepOne" | "stepTwo" | `dynamicStep-${string}`​```. So you'll never, from a type perspective at compile time, know what the actual value following the `-` in `dynamicStep-` is.